# Long list of probably worthless questions

Tags: support, questions, delete

Long list of posts was generated by running a program over the data dump for superuser. Unfortunately, the data is a bit old, and some of the questions have been removed since then. When I tried to verify the existence of these pages, I time out (I guess querying SU a couple thousand times raises some flags somewhere), so I apologize that some of these questions have been removed already. This is designed to make it easier to identify questions to delete, not to do anything else. It is LONG (and this is just the first 1/8th of the dataset)

Here is the list:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1845863#1845863

*(Mod ed: Moved to list to chat message to avoid breaking up the page)*

**EDIT 1:** [Here](http://pastebin.com/6P5SrgYJ) is a link to the code I wrote that generated this list (output is a .csv). It is pretty well documented, but I would be happy to answer any questions. It was also not written for efficiency, though the run-time on my machine is just under 12 seconds, so its not too bad.

Comment: If you can format this as a list (`- http://superuser.com/q/thing`) with each post on its own line, it would be much easier to read.

Comment: Also... you don't think this long of a list is a _bit_ excessive? Perhaps it would be better if you shared what query you ran, and the dev team could consider whether automated removal of some posts would be more appropriate. I mean we don't need to delete half the site, do we?

Comment: @nhinkle I did edit it such that each URL fits into a single line (thank you, Notepad++ macros) but again, the page becomes excessively long because of the sheer amount of links.

Comment: `cat su-urlslist.txt | while read a; do wget --quiet -O dl.txt  $a  ; [ ! -s dl.txt ] && echo Deleted: $a; done;`  this one-liner will print out urls to already deleted questions. To reverse the behaviour remove the `!`. (assuming su-urlslist.txt contains the list of urls)

Comment: @Nhinkle, link to code posted.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that questions are automatically removed [under the following conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006):

---

**If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**

- has -1 or lower score
- has no answers
- is not locked

... it will be automatically deleted.

**If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**

- has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
- has no answers
- is not locked
- has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
- has 1 or 0 comments

... it will be automatically deleted.

This check is run every week across all sites.